# MVC 3 DropdownList for Entity Object Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a Domain Entity for User and I'm trying to create a simple "update user page" in ASP.NET MVC 3. I am having trouble setting the user's Role using a @Html.DropDownListFor to **select** and **commit** the change to a role.

I use in my view I use a lot of:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
```

Here's my **User Domain Entity**. Notice how the Address and Roles are Foreign Key Properties to other classes.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Address CurrentAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

**This is my Role Entity**

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId{ get; set; }
    public string Type{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So you never want to add a user to more than 1 role? Each user in the system belongs to only one role (`User * <---> 0..1 Role`)? The standard is to have a m..n relationship between the 2 (`User * <---> * Role`)